# Link to a page inside a facebook app

Tags: facebook

I have an app inside of facebook and in that app you sign up for something and you get a personal link you can share with people to see your profile...how do I get that link inside of facebook?

An example might be in order to make this make more sense.  App lives on my server

http://example.com/app

you sign up and get a profile page

http://example.com/app/my/profile/123

I don't want to give people THAT link, because this app is for facebook only, so the page really needs to be something like facebook.com/mypage/appId/my/profile/123

tl;dr want people to directly link to a specific page inside my facebook app and I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of using http://example.com/app/my/profile/123 try using your Facebook App URL like this http://apps.facebook.com/app/my/profile/123